# How would I redirect abc.com/property/<PROPERTYID> to abc.com/<SALES/LETTINGS>/<PROPERTYID>/<PROPERTYADDRESS>

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, modx

`abc.com/property/<PROPERTYID>` to `abc.com/<SALES/LETTINGS>/<PROPERTYID>/<PROPERTYADDRESS>`

The `<PROPERTYID>` is unique so it needs some kind of query I assume?

It also needs to be programmatic so that this will work for all current and future properties.

Can this be done via .htaccess?

I'm using Modx as my CMS

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need a bit of php/js to do a lookup on the resource, grab the template variable values, then complete the redirect.